# Is there any in-universe explanation why all the fleet are girls?

Tags: kantai-collection

In Kantai Collection, as the subtitled says, "Combined Fleet Girls Collection" have all their fleet depicted as girls, known as "Fleet girls", or kanmusu.

In anime, and probably in game as well, the only guy is the admiral, and he doesn't look like one of the fleet at all. Out of universe, the admiral is the player, so he is not one of the fleet.

So, is there any in-universe canon explanation, why all the fleet are girls?

Comment: Imagining them as Fleet Boys...nah, not gonna sell.

Comment: @AyaseEri It would sell, just not to the same demographic. The Hetalia fans would probably go for Fleet Boys.

Comment: I don't know what would constitute an "in-universe canon explanation" in the context of Kancolle. There are many continuities which share little more than the characters. I can't think off-hand of any explanation in any of the works I'm familiar with, but even if there were it wouldn't apply beyond that work.

Comment: I'm not aware of any in-universe canon explanation. However, ships(countries and other vessels too) have always been referred to using the feminine form. [I've](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2010/12/ships.html) [found](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100106172805AA6cVWt) [pages](http://www.glossophilia.org/?p=1411) that might give some insight about this. The real reason as to why we do this is probably lost to history, or a combination of the theories put forth in these pages.

Answer (score 1):

I found this on a page:"Another tradition is to consider ships as female, referring to them as 'she'. ... Although it may sound strange referring to an inanimate object as 'she', this tradition relates to the idea of a female figure such as a mother or goddess guiding and protecting a ship and crew." So on, they made fleet into girls based on the sentences in top.